# css styling for commentsHolder in Blogger

Tags: html, css, blogger

```
<div id="commentsHolder">
```

Wanted to apply some padding and background color to it. I tried:

```
<style>
#commentsHolder {
background: rgba(77, 184, 255, 0.3);
padding: 18px 22px 10px;
}
</style>
```

Placed it correctly under head section.Didn't work. Any corrections?
     Thank you.

Comment: Try a _valid_ color value for background maybe …?

Comment: FYI: Validating your code before asking helps avoid the need for asking questions like this in the first place. https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: I think that we don't use padding like this, there is many paddings possible, for instance if you want the top side, you can use padding-top, same for bottom, right and left ==> padding-bottom, padding-right and padding-left

Comment: @ZiMtyth nope, that's a shortcut for padding and is correct

Comment: Tried both hex color value as well as rgb colors, didn't work.

Comment: As a first test, you can add the style inside your <div> to check if the style is correct. Make it work inside the <div>, then put it out of the <div> and deal with possible import/link of style problems.

Comment: I tried your code without a single modification, and it is working!!. You can see the result [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1ptsya00/)

Answer (score 0):

`#80cff` is not a valid colour hex
needs to be 3 or 6 characters after the #

Answer (score 0):

`#80cff` is an invalid HEX Code. Instead, try `#80cf0f` if you're trying a shade of green or provide a proper HEX Code.
The below code should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <style>
        #commentsHolder {
        background-color: #FFF;
        padding: 18px 22px 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>    
    <body>    
        <div id="commentsHolder"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Runs perfectly : https://jsfiddle.net/jvb2he3z/. Accept the answer if it works else wait for a new answer.

Comment: True. But I recently found out that there are some settings on Blogger which are 'centralized' and Google doesn't allow to change that. Your solution is perfectly allright.